# image - sRGB - dark thumbnails

Tags: image-processing

typo3-version 7.6.9 and image magick 6.7.2-7

if I set sRGB in install tool, the thumbnails in frontend are too dark, the same at "test image formats" in install tool. if i would set to RGB, the pics at "test image formats" are correct, but there are no thumbnails im frontend.

thanks a lot for help...

Answer (score 0):

have a look in the install-tool and clean up all generated images, then clear all caches (also in install-tool) and try again

Comment: thanks! i cleared all caches in install tool. if i set to RGB before, i saw the correct test images and there were no thumbnails in frontend and then everything has generated new and dark again, cause i changed to sRGB. nothing worked. could it be that the problem could solved in GraphicalFunctions.php ? Could it be that the problem are maybe some filters? i don't know which one, but maybe there is something i have not seen  ...